# Lazily evaluated property syntax difference

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

Are there any differences between the following two approaches (property with backing field and property with default value) for a lazily evaluated property or are they equivalent?

```
// (1)
public static class Foo
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Foo> instance = new Lazy<Foo>();
    public static Foo Instance { get; } = instance.Value;
}

// (2)
public static class Foo
{
    public static Foo Instance { get; } = new Lazy<Foo>().Value;
}
```

What I want to achieve is that an instance of `Foo` is created only when accessing `Foo.Instance`, not before --- more so, when `Foo.Instance` is never accessed, no instance should be created ever.

Comment: Yes, the second has no effect as it will construct the lazy object and then immediately evaluate it. The `= xxx` syntax after the property initializes the property value, and this will force the lazy object to immediately evaluate.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that's what I thought. Thank you for making this clear.

Comment: Though be aware that the first is not working either, you want this: `public static Foo Instance => instance.Value;`

Comment: So in that respect, no, they're not different :) But they're not working as intended either (I hope).

Comment: It's because you're assigning a value to `Instance` with `= new Lazy<Foo>().Value` and that's evaluated when the `Foo` is initialized. In comparison, Lasse's suggestion is effectively writing an implementation for the `get` method of the property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, actually, no, they're not different.

But, and this is just an assumption mind you, they're not working either, at least not the way I hope you intended them do.

You see, this syntax:

```
<property declaration> = <expression>;
```

Declares an initializer for the property, which will be executed on construction of the owning type.

So this:

```
private static readonly Lazy<Foo> instance = new Lazy<Foo>();
public static Foo Instance { get; } = instance.Value;
```

is not lazy at all. It will declare and construct a `Lazy<Foo>` (although you're probably missing the getter delegate here as well even though this compiles), however when you declare the property you end up with the property evaluating the lazy object upon construction of the owning type and thus it becomes non-lazy.

The second one has the exact same problem, you construct and immediately evaluate the lazy object so it becomes non-lazy.

The correct way, and this can only be achieved in sort of the first syntax form, is to use the property without an initializer, either this:

```
private static readonly Lazy<Foo> instance = new Lazy<Foo>();
public static Foo Instance
{
    get { return instance.Value; }
}
```

or this:

```
private static readonly Lazy<Foo> instance = new Lazy<Foo>();
public static Foo Instance
{
    get => instance.Value;
}
```

or probably best, as this:

```
private static readonly Lazy<Foo> instance = new Lazy<Foo>();
public static Foo Instance => instance.Value;
```

This will declare a getter *body* that doesn't execute until you actually read the property.

---

**TL;DR** To sum it up, the two examples you gave are not different, but they're both (probably) wrong and you need to change the property declaration to fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I will accept this as soon as SO lets me. It's a good answer, just one quick question: using the expression-bodied property syntax without a backing field (i.e. `public static Foo Instance => new Lazy<Foo>().Value;`) wouldn't work either, right? So there's no one-liner...?

Comment: That would construct a new lazy object and then immediately evaluate it **every time you read the property**, so no, this won't work either. Then it would be better to just `public static Foo Instance => MethodThatEvaluatesToFoo();` To my knowledge there is no one-liner for this.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587849/lazily-evaluated-property-syntax-difference/54587951#54587951) given by [Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v%C3%A5gs%C3%A6ther-karlsen), I would like to further speculate and assume that OP is after Singleton implementation. Here is a fully lazy approach.

```
Approach 1
public sealed class Singleton {
    //Private ctor of course :P
    private Singleton() {}
    // Instance property to access Singleton Instance
    public static Singleton Instance { get { return Nested.instance; } }

    private class Nested {

        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested() { }

        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}

Approach 2
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
 }
}
```